# RAILS - Remove #.VvHSzGErLVM from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sessionid, rails-i18n

I am quite new to the Ruby on Rails World.

I am trying to setup i18n for my application. I could do it by following this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

PROBLEM: when I click on a link like this one

```
<%= link_to image_tag("flags/en.png"), :locale=>'en'%>
```

The URL is appended some kind of SessionID:

```
http://localhost:3000/en#.VvHSzGErLVM
```

How can I avoid this `#.VvHSzGErLVM` to appear into the URL?

**application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale



  def set_locale
    extracted_locale = params[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header

    I18n.locale = (I18n::available_locales.include? extracted_locale.to_sym) ? 
                  extracted_locale : I18n.default_locale
  end

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ? request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first : 'pt'
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end

end
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root 'home#index'
  end
end
```